# How to handle project versioning for pre production?

Tags: version, devops, semantic-versioning

My team and I have been working on a project that is due to release early next year. A burning question that has been plaguing us is how to handle preproduction releases. For example, we have dev and staging environments that we deploy to semi-regularly so management and QA can take a peek at the progress of our project.

Since we have a few separate systems, we're trying to sync and schedule releases between systems so things operate smoothly. In production, we'd take a versioning approach to this, but we aren't at that stage yet.

How do teams handle pre-production releases? My first instinct was to just utilize semver but avoid any major bumps (e.g 1.X.X would be the production release)

Any opinions or advice on this is highly appreciated

Comment: All "0.X.X.X" versions are "not released yet" by convention, yes

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

Keep using 0.y.z while in development phase (and your API is not in prod), worry about it when in Production

---

**Long Story**

If you DO want to follow semver:

Btw, the answer is based on https://semver.org/:

SemVer 2.0 is designed as set of rules to clearly communicate the nature of the changes contained in your new release.

**X**.**Y**.**Z**
**X** - changes here represent no backward compatibility
**Y** - backward compatible new features
**Z** - backward compatible bugfixes

But it also says on [item 4](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4):
"*4. Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything MAY change at any time. The public API SHOULD NOT be considered stable.*"

You may mark your version with a pre-release tag after the version, as suggested by [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11284547/rohit), (you **may**, but you don't have to). The full spec could be:

<version core>"-"<pre-release>"+"<build>

Where:
<version core>: X.Y.Z  (as stated before)
<pre-release>: your pre-release tag (check semver site for details on what it should contain)
<build>: build identifier

The spec also gives you some hints on how to deal with versioning during development phase in the FAQ:

> **How should I deal with revisions in the 0.y.z initial development phase?**
> The simplest thing to do is start your initial development release at 0.1.0 and then increment the minor version for each subsequent release.
>
> "**How do I know when to release 1.0.0?**
> If your software is being used
> in production, it should probably already be 1.0.0. If you have a
> stable API on which users have come to depend, you should be 1.0.0. If
> you’re worrying a lot about backwards compatibility, you should
> probably already be 1.0.0."
>
> **Doesn’t this discourage rapid development and fast iteration?** 
> Major
> version zero is all about rapid development. If you’re changing the
> API every day you should either still be in version 0.y.z or on a
> separate development branch working on the next major version.

This basically says that you can stay on 0.y.z if you don't have heavy dependency on your API. If your clients treat your API as their "production" or "production ready", maybe you should move to 1.0.0 and follow the rules.

The moment you go to production you **should** be already on 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You may use SemVer technique appended with a "snapshot" followed by a timestamp. For example if the pilot version in production is 1.0.0 the pre production version can be 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT+'TIMESTAMP'. Where TIMESTAMP="The time whenever the package was generated". In this way the developer(s) will be aware of the feature that was deployed in the staging environment(s).

Let me know if this answers your question.